# Multiline \operation inside figure

Tags: floats, pgf-umlcd

I am trying to use `pgf-umlcd` to create a class diagram.  The class includes a method name with long types for the parameter, so I am using `\\` to split the definition over two lines.  The following works to create that diagram.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,notitlepage]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-umlcd}


\begin{document}
%\begin{figure}[ht] % Remove this and it works
\begin{tikzpicture}[show background grid]
  \begin{class}[text width=15 cm]{MyClass}{1, 12}
    \operation{-someMethod( longVarName : LongClassName \&, \\
      \hspace{3 cm}otherLongVarName : OtherLongClassName const \&): void}
  \end{class}

\end{tikzpicture}
%\end{figure} % Remove this and it works
\end{document}
```

I can compile this with

```
export TEXINPUTS=$HOME/doc/texmf/tex//:`kpsepath tex`; pdflatex test.tex
```

I would like to put this inside a figure, so that I can caption it and reference it elsewhere.  If I do so by uncommenting the figure lines, then it fails to compile.

```
export TEXINPUTS=$HOME/doc/texmf/tex//:`kpsepath tex`; pdflatex test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Cygwin)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
<snip>
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
! Undefined control sequence.
\\->\let \reserved@e 
                 \relax \let \reserved@f \relax \@ifstar {\let \reserved...
l.12 ...Name : OtherLongClassName const \&): void}

?
```

Replacing `\\` with `\newline` will compile, but the `\hspace` after it no longer indents.

Is there a problem with using `\\` inside a figure?  Alternately, is there a better way to do what I am trying to do within `pgf-umlcd`?

Comment: ``\protect\\`` seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reasons that are not explained in `source2e`, inside a `\parbox` the definition of `\\` is made not robust by the `\@parboxrestore` command, which is also called when starting a float.

Since the `\operation` macro does `\protected@xdef`, `\\` doesn't survive, having become fragile. So the solution is to precede it by `\protect`; even better, use `\newline` and `\hspace*{3cm}` (which is to be preferred anyway when adding space at the beginning of a line). Here are both methods:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,notitlepage]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-umlcd}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\begin{tikzpicture}[show background grid]
  \begin{class}[text width=15 cm]{MyClass}{1, 12}
    \operation{-someMethod( longVarName : LongClassName \&, \protect\\
      \hspace*{3cm}otherLongVarName : OtherLongClassName const \&): void}
  \end{class}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\begin{tikzpicture}[show background grid]
  \begin{class}[text width=15 cm]{MyClass}{1, 12}
    \operation{-someMethod( longVarName : LongClassName \&, \newline
      \hspace*{3cm}otherLongVarName : OtherLongClassName const \&): void}
  \end{class}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]